# Shiny for Python : rendering multiple plots

Tags: python, py-shiny

I am building a python shiny app where the user can select an input and then plot a graph about that input. The tricky part is that I want the app to be able to plot multiple graphs and also give the user the possibility to delete specific graphs.

So for each input I am inserting a panel containing the graph and a remove button that removes the panel when clicked on.

Everything worked fine until I added the graph in the panels.

Here is a simplified version of the code I want to make :

```
from shiny import App, render, ui, reactive
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    ui.row(
        ui.input_selectize('entry', 'User input', choices=[i for i in range(10)]),
        ui.input_action_button('submit', 'Submit'),
        id='selection_ui'
        )
    )

def server(input, output, session):
    
    session_nb_plot = reactive.Value(0)
    
    @reactive.Effect
    @reactive.event(input.submit)
    def _add():
        
        entry = input.entry()
        
        ui.insert_ui(
            make_plot(entry),
            selector='#selection_ui',
            where='afterEnd'
            )

        
    def make_plot(entry):
        
        @output
        @render.plot
        def plot_logic():
            fig = plt.figure()
            plt.plot(entry,'rD')
            return fig
        
        nb_plot = session_nb_plot.get()
        
        plot = ui.panel_well(
            ui.input_action_button('remove_'+str(nb_plot), 'Remove'),
            ui.output_plot('plot_logic'), # comment this line if you want to see how it works without the plot part
            id="to_remove_"+str(nb_plot)
            )
        
        session_nb_plot.set(nb_plot+1)
        
        return plot
   

    @reactive.Effect
    def _remove():
        
        nb_plot = session_nb_plot.get()

        if nb_plot != 0:
            for i in range(nb_plot):
                if input['remove_'+str(i)]():
                    ui.remove_ui('#to_remove_'+str(i))
            
        
app = App(app_ui, server)
```

As you can see everything goes wrong beause of the ui.output_plot call. Do you have any ideas on how I could make that work ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't add a comment since I don't have enough rep, but the issue is that your

```
ui.output_plot('plot_logic')
```

has the same id value whenever you call it and so it replaces that one plot image with whatever input the user picks again. I do not have a solution for now, but will update if I find one